# Adventureworks - Finding all the store names in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, management-studio-express

so I'm learning SQL using the sample database Adventureworks and we've been given a couple of questions and with the correct number of rows so we will know if our queries are correct or not. 
I'm having trouble finding all the store names in the database.

```
Select name from Sales.Store;
```

Returns 701 rows but the correct answer is 1000
So my question is where can I find the other 299 store names. Is there another table I have to join?

Comment: What is the actual question? You need to write query based on the requirement.

Comment: The question is Find the names of all stores in the DB and the answer should be 1000 rows.

Comment: Where are you getting that the answer should be 1000? The count in my local copy is also 701.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, the following two links both confirm that there are only 701 records in the `[Sales].[Store]` table. You should review the question or disregard the answer thats states it should be 1000.

https://www.innovasys.com/samples/dx/db/adventureworks_db~s-sales~t-store.html

http://elsasoft.com/samples/sqlserver_adventureworks/sqlserver.spring.katmai.adventureworks/table_SalesStore.htm